# Redmine installation issue

Tags: session, rake, store, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine 2.3 from SVN (http://redmine.rubyforge.org/svn/branches/2.3-stable/) 
I am using this tutorial (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowToInstallRedmineOnUbuntuServer) as Ruby is not really my piece of cake....

I'm getting an error when running a command: **rake generate_session_store**

Could not find gem 'rails (= 2.3.14)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I installed rails, but I still get the same error... searched for answers but this is really driving me crazy now.

```
:/usr/share/redmine# rails -v
Rails 2.3.14
```

Could anyone with more experience shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run to install all dependent gems `bundle install`
2. run 
   `bundle exec rake generate_session_store`
   this will call rake in scope of current installed gems.

Answer (score 0):

In Redmine 2.x you have to use

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

Instead of the old (which is for Redmine 1.4.x)

```
rake generate_session_store
```

Source: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall